# Why does a second MQTT connect result in an MQTT disconnect?

Tags: mqtt

The MQTT specification, both v3.1.1 and v5, states that if a Connect is received for a client that is already connected then the device is disconnected:

> MQTT-CONNECT: A Client can only send the CONNECT Packet once over a
> Network Connection. The Server MUST process a second CONNECT Packet
> sent from a Client as a protocol violation and disconnect the Client
> [MQTT-3.1.0-2].

In MQTT 3.1.1 this is done without any notice to the client whatsoever, in MQTT 5 the client is sent a response that it is already connected; then it is disconnected!

I am running MQTT over a cellular link from a battery operated device, and sh*t happens, sometimes the transport/device drops and, of course, I can only reconnect and the outcome of that is that I'm disconnected.  This seems completely mad to me.  I've had to implement a "try twice" on every connect in case it has happened.

Can anyone explain why this bit of specification madness exists, and persists in v5?  It can't be for security reasons as I need three strings as long as my arm (client ID, username and password) each time I connect, it is most definitely me.

And it has been explained to me that I should use an inactivity timeout of about 1.5 times my publish periodicity as a kind of workaround to disconnect my client in these circumstances but my publish is not really that periodic (it is for GNSS position establishment and how often I get that depends on the skies), so as far as I'm concerned that's a hack/workaround not an answer.

I guess there *must* be a good reason for it...?  Something I've missed about the way pub/sub works?

Comment: "I can only reconnect" - reconnecting should establish a new connection with the broker so MQTT-3.1.0-2 should not apply; instead MQTT-3.1.4-2 states that any existing connection should be dropped. This sounds like there may be an issue with your TCP stack (or possibly broker?). The MQTT spec aims for simplicity and often dropping the connection when an issue occurs is the simplest option. Enabling [keep alives](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc385349237) may help (they should only be sent if you have not already sent data within the preset interval).

Comment: I should clarify that by "reconnect" I mean "send MQTT connect once more"; so not a TCP re-connection, an MQTT reconnection.  What I think you're saying is that the specification is assuming that my MQTT client has some form of "resume" function where it remembers that it was MQTT connected and so, rather than sending MQTT connect instead re-opens socket 1883/8883 with the server and continues...?

Comment: I guess I'm asking why you are another CONNECT packet; this should only be needed when a new TCP connection is established. The spec relies upon an underlying TCP connection; as long as this remains active the MQTT connection is live (and you should not send another CONNECT packet). Some code might make it easier to understand your issue.

Comment: Unfortunately in this case the scenario crosses several device boundaries (MCU then cellular module etc.) so code doesn't really encompass it.  The issue is that the cellular module is the thing creating the socket, the IP stack is on the cellular module, all the MCU does is ask it to establish one and give it a stream of data, so if the cellular connection drops the IP connection is gone.  I had assumed that IP was simply a transport to MQTT, nothing more than that, but I think you are saying that the MQTT-level and the IP level are linked, if the transport drops so does the MQTT?

Comment: Yes, if the TCP/IP link is dropped then the MQTT connection that is running on top of it is also dropped (how would the broker know it was the same connection when it is re-established, especially since each connect will originated from a different ephemeral port). The lifetime of the MQTT level connection is bound to the life TCP/IP.

Comment: OK, in that case we're scr\*w\*d anyway 'cos the TCP connection could be dropped due to many things: cellular coverage gaps, 3GPP power saving (which could have a very short time-frame, a few 10s of seconds, for battery operated devices).  Ho hum, don't think this MQTT thingy was designed for devices connected wirelessly or powered by batteries.

Comment: @Brits said "The MQTT spec aims for simplicity": this is what I find strange, the simplest approach would be that a second connection attempt is simply accepted, job done, whereas there is this very specific (and to me counter-intuitive) requirement that it results in a [silent] disconnect.  There MUST be a reason why this is a good idea, but what is that reason?

Answer (score 0):

I believe @brits above gave the correct answer, which is that the implementation of the MQTT broker we are using has misinterpreted the specification.

We tried exactly the same scenario (MQTT connect, pull the power on the client, then MQTT connect again) with an AWS MQTT broker and the AWS MQTT broker (a) disconnected the first client and then (b) connected the second one.

In other words;

- client a.1 is MQTT connected on TCP socket x,
- client a.2 sends an MQTT connect on TCP socket y and paragraph 3.1.4-2 applies:

> if the ClientId represents a Client already connected to the Server
> then the Server MUST disconnect the existing Client [MQTT-3.1.4-2]

- hence client a.1 on TCP socket x ends up being disconnected,
- client a.2 on TCP socket y is connected perfectly normally.

Paragraph 3.1.0-2, which the MQTT broker we are using seems to be employing, and says:

> a Client can only send the CONNECT Packet once over a Network
> Connection. The Server MUST process a second CONNECT Packet sent from
> a Client as a protocol violation and disconnect the Client
> [MQTT-3.1.0-2]

...doesn't apply because the MQTT client connected on TCP socket x hasn't sent a Connect message, the one on TCP socket y has.  I think.